# Iterative running of K mean clustering algorithm inside clusters

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

I am using the k mean clustering function of MATLAB.  I need to make `K=2` every time till all the clusters match a defined condition.
If my data was

```
all_data=5*[3*rand(1000,1)+5,3*rand(1000,1)+5];
```

and I run

```
[IDX C]=kmeans(all_data,2);
```

I need to check the size of `all_data(IDX==1)` and `all_data(IDX==2)` every iteration and continue clustering with `k=2` till the size of resulting cluster reach a specific value.
How can this be implemented  in an iterative loop in MATLAB?

Comment: `kmeans(all_data,2,'Display','iter');` will show you how many points **change** classes at each iteration without stating which classes they are. I don't see the feature you're asking for in the MATLAB documentation.

Is it a possibility to implement the algorithm and track progress yourself? A simple k-means can be done in a dozen lines or so.

Comment: actually I can know the class of every point, but I still can not figure out how to make kmeans cluster inside a cluster, for example  [IDX C]=kmeans(all_data,2) will divide my data into 2 clutsers, i need to run kmeans for each one of these 2 clusters [IDX1 C1]=kmeans(all_data1,2) and [IDX2 C2]=kmeans(all_data2,2) so i end up with 4 clusters, and I continue clutser each one of these 4 clusters to get 8 new clusters, I need this to continue till until all the clusters satisfy a condition I define , for example till the size of each cluster is less than a certain value.